# Scanf pointer to a dynamic number of pointers to a dynamic number of doubles. How to store values

Tags: c

I'm declaring a pointer that points to a dynamic list of pointers that all point different dynamic lists of doubles.  How do I store the doubles this deep?  I think I know where my mistake is at (see comment in code below) I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.  here is my code:

Note: I have to use pointer arithmetic.

```
/* Variables */
int listSize;           /* The number of sets contained in the list */
double **listOfSets;    /* The list that holds all the sets */
int *listOfSetSizes;    /* The list that holds the size of each set */
int i;                  /* Counter */
int j;                  /* Counter */

/* Store Data */
printf("Enter the number of sets that will be used: ");
scanf("%d", &listSize);

listOfSets = malloc(listSize * sizeof(double *));
listOfSetSizes = malloc(listSize * sizeof(int));

for (i=0; i<listSize; i++) {
    printf("Enter the number of values in set #%d followed by\n", (i+1));
    printf("All the values in set #%d: ", (i+1));
    scanf("%d", &(*(listOfSetSizes+i)));

    *(listOfSets+i) = malloc((*(listOfSetSizes+i)) * sizeof(double));

    for (j=0; j<*(listOfSetSizes+i); j++) {
        scanf("%f", &(*((*(listOfSets+i))+j)));     /* I'm fairly certain my mistake is here */
    }
    getchar();      /* Throws away new line character after input */
}

/* Print Data */
for (i=0; i<listSize; i++) {
    printf("\nSet #%d\n", (i+1));
    printf("SetSize %d\n", *(listOfSetSizes+i));
    for (j=0; j<*(listOfSetSizes+i); j++) {
        printf("[%d]=%f\n",j, *((*(listOfSets+i))+j));
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Enter the number of sets that will be used: 2
Enter the number of values in set #1 followed by
All the values in set #1: 2 1.1 2.2
Enter the number of values in set #2 followed by
All the values in set #2: 1 3.3

Set #1
SetSize 2
[0]=0.000000
[1]=0.000000

Set #2
SetSize 1
[0]=0.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the equivalent of `&listOfSets[i][j]`, so:

```
listOfSets[i]      is    *(listOfSets + i)
listOfSets[i][j]   is  *(*(listOfSets + i) + j)
&listOfSets[i][j]  is    *(listOfSets + i) + j
```

so you're looking for:

```
scanf("%lf", *(listOfSets + i) + j);
```

Note the use of `%lf` for `double`, rather than `%f`. This matters, and differs from `printf()`.

You should also be checking the return from `malloc()` every time you call it, otherwise you don't know if your allocation succeeded.